# How can I create a dispatch table in Boo?

Tags: .net, boo, dispatch-table

I'd like to be able to store a function in a hashtable. I can create a map like:

```
hash = {}
hash["one"] = def():
   print "one got called"
```

But I'm not able to call it:

```
func = hash["one"]
func()
```

This produces the following error message: *It is not possible to invoke an expression on type 'object'*. Neither `Invoke` or `Call` works.

How can I do it ? From what I'm guessing, the stored function should be cast to something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast to a [Callable type](http://boo.codehaus.org/Callable+Types):

```
hash = {}
hash["one"] = def ():
   print "one got called"

func = hash["one"] as callable
func()
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a generic Dictionary to prevent the need to cast to a callable:

```
import System.Collections.Generic

hash = Dictionary[of string, callable]()
hash["one"] = def():
    print "got one"

fn = hash["one"]
fn()
```